# Is the invariant part of the canonical module by finite group action nonzero? 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

This is further question to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87219/injective-hulls-of-residue-fields-of-a-local-ring-and-its-ring-invariants-by-fini).

Let  $q \in V=(f=0) \subset \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ be an isolated **rational** singularity of dimension $n$. Suppose that $ G:=\mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z}$ acts on $V$ freely outside the origin. Let $U:= V/G$ be the quotient.

We have a $G$-action on the local cohomology $ H^n_{q}(V, \omega_V^{-1} ) $. Let $H'$ be the $G$-invariant part by the group action. Then

$H' \simeq H^n(U, \omega_U^{-1} ) $

and its Matlis dual is $ Hom_{\mathcal{O}_U}( \omega_U^{-1}, \omega_U) $, hence $H' \neq 0$.

Let $k$ be the residue field of the local ring $R:= \mathcal{O}_{V,0}$.

***Question (Edited!) *** Does $H'$ contain a $R$-submodule 
$N$ of $H^n_{q}(V, \omega_V^{-1} )$ such that 
$N \simeq R/m$
?

Comment: The action on the canonical module is a dual action in some sense?


Comment: It seems so. 
I added the explanation. 

Comment: I can even assume that $V$ and $V/G$ are 3-dimensional terminal singularities. 

Comment: I edited the question. 